# Transposing two columns in opposite directions and creating a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this:

|  | postal | variable | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00100 | workplaces_total_tp | 43524 | 44037 | 46945 | 45564 | 45898 | 46662 | 48470 | 50264 | 51915 | 51616 | 49712 | . |
| 1 | 00100 | q_human_health_and_social_work_a | 2075 | 2227 | 2611 | 2848 | 2815 | 2662 | 2659 | 2909 | 2938 | 2829 | 2895 | . |
| 2 | 00100 | r_arts_entertainment_and_recreat | 1582 | 1813 | 1760 | 1968 | 2237 | 2247 | 2072 | 2091 | 2151 | 2180 | 1935 | . |
| 3 | 00100 | s_other_service_activities_tp | 2158 | 2221 | 2434 | 2384 | 2381 | 2442 | 2585 | 2668 | 2516 | 2367 | 2395 | . |
| 4 | 00100 | t_activities_of_households_as_em | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | . |
| 5 | 00100 | u_activities_of_extraterritorial | 228 | 222 | 212 | 18 | 33 | 24 | 17 | 10 | 15 | 45 | 52 | . |
| 6 | 00100 | x_industry_unknown_tp | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | . |
| 7 | 00100 | other_dwellings_ra | 471 | 427 | 489 | 569 | 667 | 673 | 680 | 645 | 649 | 578 | 617 | 655 |
| 8 | 00100 | dwellings_in_blocks_of_flats_ra | 10881 | 10998 | 11102 | 11393 | 11522 | 11696 | 11766 | 11882 | 11943 | 11587 | 11721 | 11663 |
| 9 | 00100 | dwellings_in_small_houses_ra | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

I would like have the postal (codes) and the years stacked in two columns, making the dataset "long". The variable column should stretch horizontally on the column axis, making the dataset "wide".

I've tried all imaginable ways of using transpose, stack, melt and setting the index, but I just can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.melt(['postal', 'variable'], var_name='year')
   .pivot(index=['postal', 'year'], columns='variable', values='value')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
(df.set_index(['postal', 'variable'])
   .rename_axis(columns='year').stack()
   .unstack('variable').reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
variable  postal  year dwellings_in_blocks_of_flats_ra dwellings_in_small_houses_ra other_dwellings_ra q_human_health_and_social_work_a r_arts_entertainment_and_recreat s_other_service_activities_tp t_activities_of_households_as_em u_activities_of_extraterritorial workplaces_total_tp x_industry_unknown_tp
0            100  2010                           10881                            2                471                             2075                             1582                          2158                                0                              228               43524                     0
1            100  2011                           10998                            2                427                             2227                             1813                          2221                                0                              222               44037                     0
2            100  2012                           11102                            2                489                             2611                             1760                          2434                                0                              212               46945                     1
3            100  2013                           11393                            2                569                             2848                             1968                          2384                                0                               18               45564                     1
4            100  2014                           11522                            2                667                             2815                             2237                          2381                                0                               33               45898                     0
5            100  2015                           11696                            2                673                             2662                             2247                          2442                                0                               24               46662                     1
6            100  2016                           11766                            2                680                             2659                             2072                          2585                                0                               17               48470                     1
7            100  2017                           11882                            2                645                             2909                             2091                          2668                                0                               10               50264                     1
8            100  2018                           11943                            2                649                             2938                             2151                          2516                                0                               15               51915                     3
9            100  2019                           11587                            2                578                             2829                             2180                          2367                                0                               45               51616                     0
10           100  2020                           11721                            3                617                             2895                             1935                          2395                                0                               52               49712                     0
11           100  2021                           11663                            3                655                                .                                .                             .                                .                                .                   .                     .
```